# Brake pads fall out of the caliper and stuck between the caliper and the disk

Tags: brakes, disc-brake

At one moment the bike just stuck with this problem.

The brake pads fell out of the caliper and got stuck between the caliper and the disk.

I repaired it by detaching the wheel and getting it back inside, but now it keeps happening all the time.

How can this problem be solved? Is it adjustable or do I need to replace the pad or the disk/caliper?

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to replace the caliper. The caliper should hold the pads in some way, if it doesn't, it's probably broken.

Comment: Have you lost a spring/retainer/clip?   Check out new brake pads, they come with whatever clip is needed.

Comment: Your wheel is radially spoked, with a hub brake ?  That's unusual.  Do you have problems with wheel true or spokes breaking ?

Comment: @Criggie - Radially spoked is most a definite not recommended for disc brakes.  Plus only half the disc appears to be engaged by the brake pad.  There are a number of things concerned about in this setup.

Comment: Well this is a 14'' wheel of an electric bike, so maybe they thought the spokes are not long enough to break.

Comment: Anyway, problems with spikes yet I did not encounter... I will check out new brake pads. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like cheaper model calliper - many of these use a small, strong magnet to hold the pads in place. It sits in a locating hole in the centre of the 'piston' (Whats the name for the non moving one).

Unscrew the red inboard adjuster all the way and have  a look to see if there is a magnet in place (use a screw driver to feel if its there), or a hole where one should be. They are a small cylinder about 5mm diameter by 3mm.

Comment: Ahh you think the magnet may have vanished completely ?

Comment: The red thing is magnetic itself, but it's not strong at all. It holds the magnet by itself but when there's a even little friction when you trying to brake, the pad fells off. Do you think there was a stronger magnet between the red screw and the pad itself?

Comment: Pad(s) should not have enough space to come out with disc in place. Compare the caliper to the other wheel, look for cracks, bends or missing bits where the pads are inserted.